# Error in code - AttValue: " or ' expected

Tags: html, wordpress, forms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8LqF.png)

```html
<form name=“PrePage” method = “post” action = “https://Simplecheckout.authorize.net/payment/CatalogPayment.aspx”> <input type = “hidden” name = “LinkId” value =“366b94fb-808a-480b-a359-7b3d559505e9" /> <input type = “image” src =“//content.authorize.net/images/buy-now-blue.gif” /> </form>
```

I am not a developer, but I'm figuring out how to add a private page onto my client's wordpress site. It's a form page, and the code came directly from Authorize.net. Elementor flagged the error "Unexpected Character After attribute value" and LambdaTest says "AttValue: " or ' expected"

I have no idea what to do from here. Here is the code:

I tried changing all double quotes to single quotes, but I only see the button rather than full form.